# Recursive promises in ES6 with return value(s)

Tags: recursion, bluebird, es6-promise, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get content from GitHub (using [octonode](https://github.com/pksunkara/octonode)) recursively. Content is fetched recursively but the final result of the entry promise is `undefined`:

The function to fetch the content:

```
_getRepoContent ( user, repo, ref, path ) {
    return new Promise( ( resolved, rejected ) => {
        this._client.repo( user + "/" + repo, ref ).contents( path, ( err, data ) => {
            if ( err ) {
                rejected( err );
            } else {
                resolved( data );
            }
        } );
    } );
}
```

The main recursive function:

```
getContentRec ( sourceDef, data ) {

    var results = data || [];
    return this._getRepoContent( sourceDef.user, sourceDef.repo, sourceDef.ref, sourceDef.path )
        .then( ( data ) => {

            let dirs = [];
            results = results.concat( data );

            data.forEach( ( file ) => {
                if ( file.type === "dir" ) {
                    dirs.push( file );
                }
            } );

            if ( dirs.length > 0 ) {
                let promises = [];
                dirs.forEach( ( dir ) => {
                    let def = {
                        user: sourceDef.user,
                        repo: sourceDef.repo,
                        ref: sourceDef.ref,
                        path: dir.path
                    };
                    promises.push( this.getContentRec( def, results ) );
                } );
                return Promise.all( promises );

            } else {
                return Promise.resolve( results );
            }
        } )
        .catch( ( err ) => {
            return Promise.reject( err );
        } );
}
```

Calling it:

```
getContentRec( 
    { 
    user: "nodejs", 
    repo: "node"
    }
}).then( (data) => {
    // data is undefined
})
```

Any ideas? Thx a lot in advance!

Comment: Hm, there's a lot of things you can and should simplify, but I don't see anything really wrong.`getContentRec` should always return a promise that fulfills with an array.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, you are absolutely right, code could be reduced to just a subset ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, here's the solution ...:

```
getContentRec ( sourceDef ) {

    return this._getRepoContent( sourceDef.user, sourceDef.repo, sourceDef.ref, sourceDef.path )
        .map( ( content ) => {
            let def = {
                user: sourceDef.user,
                repo: sourceDef.repo,
                ref: sourceDef.ref,
                path: content.path
            };
            return content.type === "dir" ? this.getContentRec( def ) : content;
        } )
        .reduce( ( a, b ) => {
            return a.concat( b )
        }, [] );
}
```

Note:
This solution is using bluebird and not pure ES6 promises.

Comment: Is that Bluebird, not ES6-promises?

Comment: Yes, couldn't get it working without that, edited the answer to reflect that.